# File ended while scanning use of \@footnotetext

Tags: errors, debugging, sv-classes

I spell-checked my document, but somehow I must've added or deleted some '}' or something because LaTeX can't compile past a certain page, giving the error:

```
Runaway argument?
{J. Clerk Maxwell\index {Maxwell, James Clerk (1831-1879)}, \textit {\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@footnotetext.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*>
```

-

```
? H
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

I'm having a really hard time finding out what is triggering this, especially since the 87 pages of DVI that `latex` outputs before it halts looks completely fine, and Emacs's `check-parens` doesn't find any missing parens…

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Perhaps `check-parens` only checks parentheses and not `{`...`}` pairs? What does that specific `\footnote` entry look like? Can you supply us with the code?

Comment: @Werner: I have no idea what the specific `\footnote` entry is because the line number it specifies doesn't contain any code matching this `{J. Clerk Maxwell\index {Maxwell, James Clerk (1831-1879)}, \textit {\ETC.` pattern. It must've come earlier, but I've got tons of code earlier matching that form…

Comment: @Werner: Also, Emacs's `check-parens` checks quotes, brackets, curly brackets, round parens… everything.

Comment: Well then, you might just as well ask us to find a needle in a haystack. At least you can see the haystack and search for the needle. All we can do is walk around blindly, poking around in hopes we stumble upon the haystack, let alone the tiny needle. A long point to say that it's not possible to solve your problem in its current state; put yourself in the shoes of the community. Would you be able to solve someone's problem with only this amount of information?

Comment: @Werner: It's got to be a misplaced '}', then. Emacs's `check-parens` doesn't care about the _order_, just that the right number are there…

Comment: emacs' `check-parens` will blithely assume that a closing delimiter (paren, bracket, brace) that comes after a `%` (in other words, is commented out) matches an uncommented opening one.  so perhaps you have a stray comment character somewhere that is getting things out of phase.  a long shot, but worth considering.

Comment: What's even stranger is that when I comment out everything including and after the point that fails (p. 87), the LaTeX document compiles without any problems, so there can't be anything wrong before page 87.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about localized problem that may not be of much help to a wider audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a mismatched `\begin{quotation}`/`\end{quotation}` pair, which Emacs's `check-parens` could not check for.

Also, Emacs's `check-parens` did not find that there was an open '{' in a `\footnote{`. I wonder why I couldn't detect that.